# Is there a way to knock a creature out from a distance?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, unconscious, nonlethal

Per the below rules, it looks like that a PC can only [knock a creature out](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#KnockingaCreatureOut) with a melee attack:

> Sometimes an attacker wants to incapacitate a foe, rather than deal a killing blow. When an attacker reduces a creature to 0 hit points with a melee attack, the attacker can knock the creature out. The attacker can make this choice the instant the damage is dealt. The creature falls unconscious and is stable.

Is there a way to knock a creature out from a distance (e.g. with a ranged weapon or a spell) that I'm missing? Or this is not doable?

If this is up to GM discretion, would it be unbalanced to allow it?

Comment: Related: "[Can spells or spell-like abilities do non-lethal damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65686)"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, there isn't. You are not missing anything.

The rules are very clear - you can only choose to deal a non-lethal blow with a melee attack.

The way I reason is that while you can easily control a melee attack, say, by hitting with the pommel of the sword, it is quite hard to control an arrow being thrown at an almost-dead character in order to not kill it. Even if you think something along the lines of "hitting his legs", the fact that he is low HP (enough for 1 attack to kill him) means he's already heavily injured (or he is very squishy to begin with), which probably means even the blood loss from the arrow piercing the leg would be lethal.

Obviously this is not completely accurate to real life, but we are in a world with Fireballs, so... yeah.

### I don't see any problem with house-ruling the other way, though

I have allowed many times for my ranged player characters to deal non-lethal blows, sometimes by telling them the AC would be increased (since it would require more precision), sometimes by simply allowing it. I don't see how it would be a problem in any way, and never had any kind of problem following it. I may also ask them to actually perform medicine and stabilize the enemy character in these cases, so he won't bleed to death.

Usually all of this comes as just improvisation and I go along what will make the players more satisfied, honestly. As I said, I never had any kind of problem allowing it.

### The rules do allow the DM to use Death Saving Throws rules for NPCs

So, you can always use that. The NPC will not instantly die, it has to make some death saves. The characters can then work to stabilize or even heal the knocked NPC. Usually, using Death saves for NPCs is reserved to important and powerful NPCs, but nothing is stopping you from using it to random thugs.

Comment: For my most recent session I had every NPC roll death saves, because the conflict was a schism within a faction and both sides wanted to avoid unnecessary casualties. Between characters succeeding their saves, medicine checks to stabilize, and healing magic, almost no one wound up dead and the next session will start with the PCs needing to handle a ton of unconscious prisoners. So while I agree that a houserule is fine, it may not be necessary.

Comment: Just a bone of contention, there is no such thing as "non-lethal damage" in 5E. You simply opt to render someone unconscious when they reach zero hit points.

Comment: @Slagmoth There is no such thing as "Non-Lethal Damage" there is however damage that is non-lethal. which seems pretty obvious that this is the case here.

Answer (score 20):

### Yes, with a ranged spell that does a melee attack

Arguably, you can knock them out at range with a *Spiritual Weapon* attack or the *Clenched Fist* from *Bigby's Hand*, or when attacking with spells like *Animate Objects* or *Mordenkainen's Sword*.
While your DM may not agree, we'll walk through the logic on this. Using as an example *spiritual weapon* (which reaches out to 60 feet away) ...

#### What does *Spiritual Weapon* do?

It makes a melee spell attack on a creature. (Ch 11, Level 2, Range 60')

> You create a floating, spectral weapon within range that lasts for the duration or until you cast this spell again. When you cast the spell, you can make ***a melee spell attack*** against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon. On a hit, the target takes force damage...

Is this a melee attack? Yes, a melee spell attack is still a melee attack, even if it has a longer reach than 5' away.

#### Melee Attacks (Ch 9)

> ... a melee attack allows you to attack a foe within your reach. A melee attack typically uses a handheld weapon such as a sword, a warhammer, or an axe. A typical monster makes a melee attack when it strikes with its claws, horns, teeth, tentacles, or other body part. *A few spells also involve making a melee attack*. Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions.

Spiritual weapon's 'reach' is up to 60'.

#### A melee spell attack is a kind of melee attack.

*Shocking Grasp* (*Make a melee spell attack against the target*) and *Inflict Wounds* (*Make a melee spell attack against a creature*) are other exmples of spell attacks that are also melee attacks.

Knocking a Creature Out (Ch 9)

> When an attacker reduces a creature to 0 hit points ***with a melee
> attack***, the attacker can knock the creature out.

Here's the logic train: a melee spell attack is a melee attack, *spiritual weapon* is a spell that makes a melee attack with a range/reach of up to 60', it takes a melee attack to knock a creature out (rather than kill it) when an attack that drops them to 0 HP, thus you can use *spiritual weapon* to knock out a foe at range.

#### *Reach out, reach out and touch someone!*

I am confident that this logic also works for:
*Bigby's Hand* (Clenched Fist). (Ch 11, level 5 spell, range 120')

> The hand strikes one creature or object within 5 feet of it. Make a melee spell attack for the hand using your game statistics. On a hit, the target takes 4d8 force damage.

*Animate Objects*(Ch 11, level 5 spell, rang 120')

> If you command an object to attack, it can make a single melee attack
> against a creature within 5 feet of it.

From *Mordenkainen's Sword* (Ch 11, 7th level spell, range 60')

> When the sword appears, you make *a melee spell attack* against a target
> of your choice *within 5 feet of the sword*.  On a hit, the target takes
> 3d10 force damage.

#### At table experience

I've not yet had a DM disagree with the above logic. When I DM this is an option if the PC or NPC is wielding their *spiritual weapon*.  (This once allowed me to  have an NPC knock out a fleeing PC rather than kill them ... after which the rest of the party had to rescue them later ... )
As for the higher level spells, none of us thought to knock the enemies out in the fights where I saw those used by wizards.  But I think we could have.

Credit and thanks to @NautArch for getting me to check spells other than *spiritual weapon*

#### You familiar may be able to help you reach out ...

You might be able to knock them out at range if your familiar lays your *shocking grasp* (melee spell attack) on them and you do enough damage. (@z33k thank you!)

Comment: excellent point and idea! The *spiritual weapon* is ranged from the caster, but offers a melee attack. *Bigby's hand* would work, too! Although now that I think about it, there's a LOT of things that fall under this - included conjured creatures.

Comment: Bingo. I would hope the OP "accepts" this answer, as it's really the only correct one to the question asked.

Comment: @TimGrant Thanks for your vote of confidence, glad to see that you are still around ... :-)

Comment: The monk way of the four elements has a feature, Fangs of the Fire Snake, that increase the reach of the monk's unarmed strikes by 10'

Comment: @GcL: hmm, not a spell, but a way to "reach" for such an attack ... I need to read up on the feature, do not have PHB at the mo, seems a good coda

Comment: And remeber that with a familiar you can deliver a touch spell from afar...I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this so far.

Comment: Since all the examples were leveled spells, Thorn Whip is also a melee spell attack w/ range 30 ft but as a cantrip so can be used more often.

Comment: Thanks, any spell that makes a melee attack is good to go.  I'll see if I can find the right place to slide that in...

Answer (score 2):

## Ranged spells

Depending on what consititues a knock-out for you, the **Sleep** spell is ranged, renders the target unconscious and since it doesn't deal damage you don't need to worry about having to stabilise the target. of course, the difference is that the target isn't on 0HP and the capability of the target to recover quickly from being unconscious might matter.

Other spells which can render a target unconscious include **Eyebite** and **Catnap** (XGE).

## Ranged weapons

I believe that yes you *should* be able to knock someone out from a distance, and that is is a shame that the 5e rules don't accommodate this. We use a house rule in our campaigns. It is a very simple extension of the K/O rule for melee combat:

**Damage from blunt projectiles (house rule):**

> If a character, *making a ranged attack with blunt projectiles*, reduces an
> opponent to 0 HP then the target becomes unconscious and stable, similar to
> a melee K/O.

**In play:**

Allow the players different types of arrows, including ones with blunt tips, which deal bludgeoning damage instead of piercing. For simplicity we grant these arrows the same damage, cost and size/encumbrance (20 per quiver) as normal arrows.

Most of the archers in our campaigns quickly learn to buy a handful of these "blunts" from a fletcher when the opportunity arose. The player has to specifically annouce that they want to incapacitate a target with a blunt when they rather than kill with a normal arrow head.

This also presented benefits to archers when attacking anything with a vulnerability to bludgeoning; in our campaigns this was especially useful when facing skeletons. It also gives options when engaging with targets that are immune or resistant to piercing damage. A caveat to the last point: many monsters which are resistant to piercing damage are also often resistant to bludgeoning damage (e.g. swarms, trees).

An unexpected side effect, which we embraced, was that blunt projectives such as stones from slings would no longer kill an opponent. This added a role-playing opportunity with a druid character who (1) preferred not to kill opponents and (2) was thus more vulnerable to enemies who could regain consciousness.

With the exception of the poor skeletons who got clobbered, the players didn't use the blunts too often--there is little need to capture and interrogate most monsters. Even with the option to knock someone out with a ranged weapon, the players would usually opt for either face-to-face confrontation or possibly mass-effect spells such as Sleep. Going back to those skeletons, it's easy enough to add a few more into the mix to soak up the ranged attacks with a limited supply of blunt arrows.

While it hasn't impacted our own campaign, and we haven't needed to word the rule specifically, it should be understood that "blunt projectiles" are relatively small; a direct hit by a boulder hurled by siege engines could still kill.

**Afterthought**: Having had to explain all this in writing, I see a loop-hole in our house rule. The skeletons who should have been pulverised by virtue of being vulnerable to bludgeoning weapons *technically* should have simply been incapacitated when knocked down to 0 HP. I guess we didn't feel the need to specify that creatures vulnerable to bludgeoning damage would be killed rather than knocked out.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying bludgeoning never kills? Or that you are allowing ranged attackers an option with this? My big concern, and I'd love to hear how it went at the table, is that ranged weapon users have an advantage of not having to close distance. GIving them more options for weapon attacks alters that and gives a big reason to go ranged over melee.

Comment: The wording of our rule is that *ranged attacks with blunt projectiles* (blunt arrows, stones from slings) do not kill. Other bludgeoning weapons, inc. melee, would act as normal. I can add a bit more about how the players used this...

Comment: Did that cause any weirdness with not picking blunt ranged weapons? That really does make things like *magic stone* less interesting.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think any of the players in my campaign found *Magic Stone* interesting in the first place. I see it is from EE, which we haven't been using as one of our source books. That might be a missed opportunity, as this could have suited our druid quite well! The rest of the characters are a bit more... bloodthirsty.

Comment: *Magic stone* was also printed in *Xanathar’s Guide*.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt There's a phone call for you on line 1; it's a musket ball. He wants to discuss how a ranged attack with a blunt object can't kill, and he is somewhat adamant that Bess Brown's daughter isn't his child.  On line 2 we have a guy called Thor who is asking if you'd like a taste of his hammer ... will you take either call, or shall I tell them that you are in conference? 

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Objection! Experiments conducted by the ACME Corporation have demonstrated to an alrming degree of statistical significance that ranged attacks dealing bludgeoning damage cannot, in fact, kill. ACME has collected results from numerous trials involving a live coyote by the name of Wile E. The test subject repeatedly had a steel anvil dropped on his head from a great height, and while frequently showed signs of injury, never died.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It was a thin coating of steel foil over a balsawood anvil .... or didn't you get the memo on that? The 'truth in advertising' case is still under appeal ...

Comment: :) We've not encountered muskets or magical flying hammers yet in our world. I suspect that we'd consider death rather than KO under the instant death rules when total damage dealt is more than total HP.

Comment: I'd rule that an anvil-as-a-projectile is similar to siege weapon ammo. Maybe Mjölnir too. I'll have to discuss with the group but we've not needed to write the rule explicitly for such things. Side thought: Is a falling anvil a "ranged attack"?