# May a character switch from a druidic to an arcane focus without expending an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

If a multiclass Sorcerer/Druid wielding a shield and an arcane focus decides to cast a druid spell, can they switch their focus and cast the spell in a single turn?

Secondarily, is it reasonable for both to be tied to the belt with a leather thong, so that neither are ever dropped on the floor?

Comment: Related: [Can a character drop a weapon in order to cast a spell that is a reaction?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59124),  [Can an item be both an arcane and a divine focus?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71364) and [Can a multi-class spellcaster have one thing be two different focuses?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77256)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As shown in the linked questions, *it depends*.

The rules don't specify an action cost for dropping something - does this mean it has no action cost, or does it fall under "interact with an object"? If it's the first, then you can drop one focus, then "interact" to pick up the other as part of your spellcasting action. If it's the second, then you're using your "interact" to drop (or put away) your current focus, and don't have a chance to pick up the other. Ask your DM.

As an alternative, some foci *might* be able to be used for both sorcerer and druid. Sorcerer lists a wand; druid lists a *yew* wand. Sorcerer lists a staff; druid lists a *wooden* staff. Does this mean a single yew wand or wooden staff can be the focus for both classes? Maybe. Ask your DM.

Another alternative is a component pouch. It is a pouch you can hang on your belt, that contains all material components that don't have listed costs. This *can* be used by all spellcasting classes, no question. And drawing out the components is covered by "interact", so can be done as part of the spellcasting action.

Comment: Actually druid lists a yew wand( or wooden staff), while a sorcerer lists a wand or specially constructed staff "designed to channel the power of arcane spells", meaning they have been specially modified with whatever the equivalent of magic-item circuitry is, like runes and channels. I think this goes against the idea of a druidic focus, which would need to be whole and un-defiled. There is already an item which does both, which is a component pouch, as you said, and the arcane and druidic focus as listed as separate items, which each class using one or the other to cast spells.

Comment: @Zso *"...they have been specially modified with whatever the equivalent of magic-item circuitry is, like runes and channels"* - this is not specified, so is open to interpretation. Like I said, "Maybe. Ask your DM."

Comment: Or however you want to phrase it. They've been modified for Arcane Power use instead of remaining whole and with their connection to nature. Lore-wise it's open to interpretation, but in game terms it's not. There are no dual-foci in the rules, and foci cannot be combined in this way. Anything like this would have to be a homebrew.

Comment: @Zso If you disagree, you should add an answer of your own instead of commenting on this one.