# What determines what type of spell casting focus I may use for a spell I obtained outside of my class spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer

My intention for this is to allow my 5th level Alchemist Artificer to cast Toll the Dead through their Tools as is required to get the bonus from Alchemical Savaant.

> At 5th level, you develop masterful command of magical chemicals, enhancing the healing and damage you create through them. Whenever you cast a spell using your alchemist’s supplies as the spellcasting focus, you gain a bonus to one roll of the spell. That roll must restore hit points or be a damage roll that deals acid, fire, necrotic, or poison damage, and the bonus equals your Intelligence modifier (minimum of +1).

I cannot find anywhere, anything that says I cannot cast a spell not on my list through my classes focus and I just want to clarify this.

Comment: Related on [Can an item be both an Arcane and Divine focus?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71364) and [Can a multiclass spellcaster have one thing be two different focuses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77256/can-a-multi-class-spellcaster-have-one-thing-be-two-different-focuses)

Comment: *Prestidigitation* doesn't have a material component, and thus foci are irrelevant for that spell.  Maybe use, say, *dancing lights* as the example spell instead?

Comment: I think you also need to separate out racial feature vs from a feat.

Comment: The second one isn’t related to the question.

Comment: *Fire bolt* doesn't have a material component either.

Comment: You don’t have to have a Material Component to use a SpellCasting Focus so the component doesn’t matter. My main goal is to get my Alchemist to be able to cast a Toll the Dead through his tools but I cannot find anything addressing this online specifically as a possibility or not.

Comment: If that's your actual question, you should edit this to ask it :) We do best when we're solving a specific problem. It seems like you want to ask whether or not an Alchemist can cast a spell through their focus (their tools) when a focus isn't required because the spell doesn't have a material component.

Comment: You can do that regardless. A spell focus can cast any spell through it without material components, it just has no extra benefit. But this spell isn’t on their class list and I wonder if that changes things.

Comment: If I gain the ability to cast Toll the Dead, May i cast it through my Alchemist tools so I may gain the extra (Int Mod) in damage bonus gained by casting a necrotic spell through my tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A focus is only good for spells that come from the class spell list.

Each class that has the "Spellcasting Focus" class feature has the same general rules text: "You can use a [type] focus as a spellcasting focus for your [class] spells."

In those cases, the focus is only good for spells that come from your class spell list.

The Artificer is a little different, but the "Tools Required" class feature has a similar general thrust:

> You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools.

It goes on to give details about what tools count and so on, but the overarching idea is that this is all about how to cast spells *as an Artificer*. It doesn't explicitly say they *only* count as a spellcasting focus for artificer spells, so your DM could rule otherwise, but that's how it reads to me -- a spell you acquire in any other way (feats, multiclassing, etc) would not be able to use your tools as a focus, and would consequently not be eligible for use with your Alchemical Savant ability.

But it doesn't really matter. You can only use a focus for spells that require material components, which *toll the dead* does not. In the case of the artificer, "Tools Required" makes an exception and says EVERY artificer spell needs a focus even if it otherwise wouldn't, but that still wouldn't apply to spells acquired from another class.

No matter which way you turn it, you can't use Alchemical Savant with *toll the dead*.

Answer (score 3):

## No focus necessary

*[Toll the dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/toll-the-dead)*(XGtE, 169) has no material component(only verbal and somatic) so a focus is not part of the spellcasting process. Because it is not used, the Alchemist feature is not activated.