# How to become a paladin without actually becoming a Paladin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

[**Hope of Humanity Spoilers Ahead**]

For my homebrew campaign, currently dubbed "Hope of Humanity" one of my PCs is playing a character who believes he is a Paladin of the dead god Aroden (but he actually is just taking magus levels as a means of illustrating his abilities; we've decided he can't be a real paladin of a dead god) and I wanted to see if there were any pieces I could work into the campaign that would essentially grant him paladin-like abilities without taking Paladin levels.

Currently, the only things I've found are the [Bloodstones of Arazni](http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/magic-items/artifacts/major-artifacts/bloodstones-of-arazni), specifically the Heart as it grants *Lay on Hands*. Are there any other methods to grant other paladin abilities to a non-paladin, like *Auras, Detect Evil, Smite Evil, Mercy*, or *Channel Positive Energy*?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? If you want Paladin features, why don't you just play a Paladin? If you want him to stay not-a-real-Paladin, why do you want him to get real Paladin features?

Comment: Related to KRyan's question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77126/how-can-i-persuade-my-dm-to-play-my-warlocks-patron-in-a-way-that-respects-my-c/77136#77136

Comment: Just a note, **worshippers of Aroden gain no powers** right now on the official campaign setting (of course, it's your game and you can change that). That is why most clerics and paladins of Aroden now follow Iomedae (his former herald), or simply converted to another deity.

Comment: 1. Is this an existing character, who has already seen play? 2. What level is the character currently (starting at, if not already playing), and what levels do you expect to reach in the campaign?

Answer (score 5):

There is a feat that grants lay on hands 1/day it is called [Believer's hands](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/feats.html#believers-hands). It's prerequisite, believer's boon (directly above believer's hands) grants one use of a 1st level domain ability granted by your god.

For making the magus more paladin like I'd suggest taking the eldritch scion archetype with the celestial bloodline. Even if its *Angelic Attacks* is by far weaker than smite evil it at least lets you ignore some DR and deals more damage to evil outsiders.

An option to become more paladin-like would be the [chevalier](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Chevalier) prestige class. But as it doesn't increase spellcasting that would, most likely, not be the best choice optimization wise.

Comment: This is a good suggestion because it removes the need for the character to maintain a spellbook, making the idea that he might think he's a paladin more believable to him.

Comment: I kind of got the impression that this was an existing character? I could be wrong though.

Comment: I thought it unclear whether the game already started but rereading it you might be right.

Answer (score 3):

The 7th-level cleric, 4th-level paladin spell [*bestow grace of the champion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bestow-grace-of-the-champion/) does basically this, granting the target detect evil, smite evil, lay on hands, divine grace, and immunity to fear and disesase for 1 round/level.

Having this spell effect apply to the magus on some limited basis would be a great way to accomplish partial paladin-hood. But the spell is much, much too powerful to have effecting the magus all the time.

Comment: "But the spell is much, much too powerful to have effecting the magus all the time."

Opinion, and very unexplained.  Maybe explain how much of a power boost this is instead of telling OP that an otherwise seemingly perfect solution isn't what he should do?

Comment: @godskook It's a 7th level spell with a duration normally measured in rounds. It seems pretty obvious to me that that would be too powerful to make permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider allowing him to be a real paladin. Some force out there may answer his prayers, and grant him power because they feel he is worthy and honor his devotion for the lost deity. Perhaps even a neutral good power that doesn't necessarily believe in following all the rules all the time. He would be an actual paladin, just not backed by the power of Aroden as he believes. It requires a little DM hand waving, but could make for an interesting story.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows that's an option, and this doesn't answer the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is about a year later but I just found a Prestige Class that would give your player a couple of Paladin Powers.  The Chevalier is just a three level class that gives an Aura of Courage, as well as an additional save from enchantments, and at 3rd level poison immunity and a single use of Smite Evil per day.  It is a pretty good alternative to pally.

[Chevalier Prestige Class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/chevalier/)

Comment: This is accurate, but it’s a terrible choice for a magus, as the class relies entirely on spells and chevalier doesn’t do anything for them.