# How important is the War Caster feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

I've seen multiple people who have beelined for the feat of War Caster, but I never really understood this. While I can see some situations that this would be good (Polymorph comes to mind...), it doesn't seem to be worth most of your racial bonuses with the variant human or the ability score increase.
The reason I want to know this is because I have a 7th level sorcerer, nearing 8th, and I want to know if this would help.

So is it worth it?

Comment: Its value will depend on several factors. Namely, how often do you use concentration spells and how often are you likely to be hit. If you can provide your typical spell choices in combat and information about the other members of your party, you will likely get better, more specific answers based on your situation.

Comment: "Is it worth it" is mostly an opinion-based determination, and depends heavily on what other options you're considering (and what your current ability scores are). If you want to compare it to some other specific feat options, that might be easier to determine.

Answer (score 4):

What role is your sorcerer playing in the party?

### For support casters it's a great help

If you are a spell caster *who is casting a lot of **concentration** spells*, having advantage on the Constitution save if you take damage, so that you are less likely to lose your concentration, is really helpful not just for sorcerers.

My clerics always get it.
My druids always get it.
Sorcerers who buff their allies and debuff their enemies ought to get it.

I don't want my concentration spells to drop.  I want them to stay up.

- *Flaming Sphere?*  Keep it burning all fight long.
  *Bless?*    Helps my party.
  *Spirit Guardians?*   Keep mowing and slowing the enemies.
  *Entangle?*     Slow the enemy down, let my martials kill them.   Slow?    Debuff the enemy, give them disadvantage on Dex saves.
  *Call Lightning?*  Yes.  Keep bringing down 3d10 each round.
  *Haste?*  Make my martials blenders on two feet.
  *Wall of Ice?*  Keep that wall up!
  *Flying?*  Keep that concentration up to avoid a crash landing!

[This answer shows benefits of the feat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130722/22566)  I borrowed the graph from that answer to illustrate.

[image]
Your sorcerer is already proficient in Constitution saves, so War Caster is an additive benefit.  To get an idea for how high your chances are to avoid losing concentration thanks to the feat, you move the target number to the left based on your proficiency and constitution, and only use the blue lines.

- Example: your Constitution is 12 (+1 mod, dashed blue line) and your level is seven or eight (Prof bonus +3) so your move left on the graph is 4.  If the DC is 10 (someone just did 20 damage to the Sorcerer) your target number is 6 (nearly
  guaranteed). If the DC is 15 (someone just did 30 damage to the Sorcerer) the target number is 11( ~83% chance of success to keep your concentration spell going).

For keeping concentration spells up, War Caster is a good choice all game long.
Numbers wise concerning advantage:  if for this ASI you raised your Constitution from 14 to 16, you would get a +1 on your roll to avoid breaking concentration when taking damage.  With Advantage from the feat, you are getting roughly [a +4 to +5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14690/22566) benefit on a given roll.

Being able to use a spell as an opportunity attack is icing on the cake.

#### Does this help a blaster-style sorcerer?

If you are playing more of a 'blaster' and less of a 'support' sorcerer then a boost in your casting stat is a better choice (make the spell's DC go up) or if Charisma is already maxed out, a feat like Elemental Adept.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a little off-- a boost in your casting stat is basically always better-- but you max that stat out pretty quick, usually, so then feats like this are totally worth it over e.g. +2 dex or +2 con.

Comment: It's notable that Resilient(Con) isn't applicable for Sorcerers, since they are proficient in Con saves by default.

Comment: @Miniman that's a good point

Comment: If my experience, if you are in the back and the melee types do their job properly, you are hardly ever damaged.

Comment: @András my experience is very, very different from yours.  Ranged attackers and AoE, giants throwing rocks ... there are all kinds of ways that the enemy tactics find ways to hit casters.  That will also depend on how a DM runs the monsters: smart, medium, or as drones.  It varies.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast let me put it another way; if Sorcerers (with Con save prof) _need_ Warcaster, than every other caster, that have neither would simply be unviable. I do not see that being the case.

Comment: (I would turn that into an answer, but the question is on hold)

Comment: @András that's an interesting way to approach it.  I based my answer on a support style rather than a blaster. (And FWIW, the feats are optional rules ... ) .  IMO, the WC feat is a very valuable feat for the support caster approach to full spell caster PC's.  For a blaster?  Not so much.